# Simulating ESP8266 server multithreading

Tags: lua, esp8266

Can't seem to find this anywhere online, so I figure I'll ask here.

I have multiple ESP8266 modules that I'm using for my home security system. My current setup works beautifully: my acquisition server polls my ESP8266 units and asks for their current I/O states (if a door is open or closed). My system polls my 3 ESP8266 modules once per second. I would like to change my setup to allow for the 8266s to keep local alarms (do local I/O checking), while my system only polls once per minute or so.

My problem is that I am having trouble programming the 8266 modules to check their own I/O status and set alarms, etc, while simultaneously running a web server to receive the polling requests from my acquisition server.

I've tried quite a few things, but can't quite seem to make it work. Here's a sample test that I've run to see if I can make the WHILE loop work simultaneously with the server.

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATIONAP)
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.setip({ip="192.168.1.110",netmask="255.255.255.0",gateway="192.168.1.254"})
wifi.sta.config("someSSID","somePW")
srv=net.createServer(net.TCP)

someint = 5
a = 1
while a do
    someint = someint + 1
    srv:listen(8080,function(conn)
        conn:on("receive", function(client,request)
            client:send(someint);
            client:close();
            collectgarbage();
        end)
    end)
end
```

It doesn't have the expected results (the response incrementing from 5,6,7,etc.) I've tried other conditions on my WHILE loop such as "while true do", etc., but nothing seems to work.

For simplicity's sake, I'll ask this and figure it out from there...is there some way to make the number someint increment while also listening for incoming connections? I don't want the number to only increment once a new connection comes in, I want it to increment forever until a new connection comes in, then continue once the connection is closed.

If you need me to elaborate, I'd be happy to. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question because it seems trivial (hence, I must be wrong). https://gist.github.com/marcelstoer/76fbe0717037498b94bdf866f2748bdd untested.

Comment: I do not know the lua net library but, the listen function may wait till a connection is made, then your only possibility is produce multiple threads, a.k.a. coroutines...

Comment: Instead of polling I use event-based messaging with MQTT, this is much more efficient and resource-friendly imo.